# Adobe XD prototyping - hover inside components doesn't work when cursr moves from one area to another

Tags: hover, adobe, prototype

I've got this strange issue when prototyping horizontal hover mega menu.
I've got currently two menu items and they should display mega menu on hover.
Strange thing is - it's working only when i move cursor out of component and go back - when i'm trying to hover one after another - nothing happens.

Here is the video: https://youtu.be/T9P0lyL3fgg

I was already trying by creating this with two approach like here - with seperated hover area inside component that leads to different state of same main component:

https://tomb.pl/screen.png

And in the second approach  i've created two seperated components for every menu item that should go to it's own hover state:

https://tomb.pl/screen-02.png

Unfortunetly - both approaches works like in the video showed above.
Which is strange - cause as far i understand that the second one can make the hovered component above another but in the first one - they are totally seperated areas.

**UPDATE:**
I was trying different approaches but i still didn't found any solution for this problem. Right now i'm thinking of changing the shape of the component to something like this:

[image]

But the question is - if this is even possible?

Thanks